# Google Crawler in Search Console can't found routes in React using Github Page

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router, github-pages, google-crawlers

My problem is **Crawl** in **Google Search Console** can't found sub-routes in **React**.

The URL is https://huynhsamha.github.io/crypto, and crawler can `fetch and render` homepage (route `/`) and static files such as `/robots.txt`, `/favicon.ico`, but it can't found the sub-routes, which are rendered by React, (**SPA**, using `Redux`), such as `/algorithm/sha256`. Example, https://huynhsamha.github.io/crypto/algorithm/sha256 can't found by Crawler but it can be accessible.

This is my screenshot in Google Search Console I've tried.

[image]

Who can explain why and how to fix my problem? I'm using `react-router-dom` with `react-redux` My repository on github [here](https://github.com/huynhsamha/crypto)

**Edit 1**

I've also tried the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/53966338/8828489 in this question, but not working. I've added script in `index.html` (https://github.com/huynhsamha/crypto/blob/gh-pages/index.html), but search console can't still found, so it also can't render any error on screen.

**Edit 2**

I've also tried the answers https://stackoverflow.com/a/54040745/8828489 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/54048119/8828489 in this question, but not working. I've created **404.html** file and add scripts as the answer instructs but it didn't also work.

**Edit 3**

I've also tried the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/54044148/8828489 in this question by creating a simple `sitemap.xml`, googlebot can find this file and discover all URLs I defined in sitemap. But it also cannot fetch and render URLs mentioned.

Answer (score 5):

I poked around in your source code and don't see anything alarming; however, I found a few posts about similar issues [(1)](https://blog.codaxy.com/debugging-googlebot-crawl-errors-for-javascript-applications-5d9134c06ee7) [(2)](https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/comments/825n75/google_doesnt_index_my_react_app/dv7l3tq). The second seems particularly helpful, so I'll repeat it here. Shout out to @Zerotorescue on Reddit.

Open Google Search Console and go to Crawl -> Fetch as Google and do a fetch and render.

Add this to your site, either as a part of  tag in your HTML file or as part of the bundle:

https://gist.github.com/mstijak/715fa2dd3f495a98386c3ebbadbabb8c

I recommend the former since that makes it easier to change if you need to make it more readable (no need to recompile your app).

Push this to your site and then do another fetch and display. The error preventing Google from running your app will now show. The search console resolution is pretty low so you may have to increase the font-size of the error and fetch again. Don't worry, Google doesn't mind repeated calls.

You'll probably find that Google's crawler can't process your code because you're using some ES6 feature it doesn't support. You can fix this by polyfilling. I've tried a couple of things such as https://polyfill.io/ which turned out to not really support Googlebot and while it might sometimes work, it is pretty unreliable. Instead I recommend using babel-polyfill. It will increase your bundle size a little bit for everyone but in my experience it provides the widest browser support with a minimal headache. Just turn it on and you're done.

If you're using create-react-app this is the polyfills.js file I use that you could copy:

https://github.com/WoWAnalyzer/WoWAnalyzer/blob/2c67a970f8bd9026fa816d31201c42eb860fe2a3/config/polyfills.js#L1

Notice there are a lot of comments explaining all the issues the polyfill service introduce that you won't have to deal with if you use babel-polyfill.

Comment: I've tried and it's still not working. I've added script in index.html https://github.com/huynhsamha/crypto/blob/gh-pages/index.html, but search console can't found, so it also can't render any error on screen.

Answer (score 5):

I found that when i opened https://huynhsamha.github.io/crypto/algorithm/sha256, I actually received a 404 as a [response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R9CZv.png). I think your workaround for hosting SPA on GitHub using the `404.html` is the issue here. While us humans see your app being served on our browser correctly, googlebot doesn't care and just look at the response code and see that it has received a `404`. You'll need a different workaround that doesn't involves using the `404.html` as the entry point to your app directly.

Try following [this workaround by rafrex](https://github.com/rafrex/spa-github-pages) instead, it redirects the browser to `index.html` using the `404.html` while keeping the original route, it claims that googlebot register that as a `301` instead of a `404`, for your case that means adding these changes below to your site, pay attention to the script below the `<!-- ------Single Page Apps GitHub Pages Workaround------ -->`:

```html
<!-- 404.html -->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Cryptography</title>

    <!-- ------Single Page Apps GitHub Pages Workaround------ -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
      // Single Page Apps for GitHub Pages
      // https://github.com/rafrex/spa-github-pages
      // Copyright (c) 2016 Rafael Pedicini, licensed under the MIT License
      // ----------------------------------------------------------------------
      // This script takes the current url and converts the path and query
      // string into just a query string, and then redirects the browser
      // to the new url with only a query string and hash fragment,
      // e.g. http://www.foo.tld/one/two?a=b&c=d#qwe, becomes
      // http://www.foo.tld/?p=/one/two&q=a=b~and~c=d#qwe
      // Note: this 404.html file must be at least 512 bytes for it to work
      // with Internet Explorer (it is currently > 512 bytes)
      // If you're creating a Project Pages site and NOT using a custom domain,
      // then set segmentCount to 1 (enterprise users may need to set it to > 1).
      // This way the code will only replace the route part of the path, and not
      // the real directory in which the app resides, for example:
      // https://username.github.io/repo-name/one/two?a=b&c=d#qwe becomes
      // https://username.github.io/repo-name/?p=/one/two&q=a=b~and~c=d#qwe
      // Otherwise, leave segmentCount as 0.
      var segmentCount = 1;
      var l = window.location;
      l.replace(
        l.protocol + '//' + l.hostname + (l.port ? ':' + l.port : '') +
        l.pathname.split('/').slice(0, 1 + segmentCount).join('/') + '/?p=/' +
        l.pathname.slice(1).split('/').slice(segmentCount).join('/').replace(/&/g, '~and~') +
        (l.search ? '&q=' + l.search.slice(1).replace(/&/g, '~and~') : '') +
        l.hash
      );
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

```html
<!-- index.html -->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">
  <meta name="description" content="Cryptography Algorithms: Secure Hash Algorithm (sha256, sha512, ...), Message Digest Algorithm (md5, ripemd160), HMAC-SHA, HMAC-MD, pbkdf2, Advanced Encryption Standard (AES), Triple Data Encryption Standard, (TripleDES, DES), RC4, Rabbit, ...">
  <meta name="keywords" content="crypto, algorithms, secure hash, sha, sha512, sha256, message digest, md5, hmac-sha, aes, des, tripledes, pbkdf2, rc4, rabbit, encryption, descryption">
  <meta name="author" content="huynhsamha">

  <!-- Open Graph -->
  <meta property="fb:app_id" content="440168923127908">
  <meta property="og:url" content="https://huynhsamha.github.io/crypto">
  <meta property="og:title" content="Cryptography Algorithms">
  <meta property="og:description" content="Cryptography Algorithms: Secure Hash Algorithm (sha256, sha512, ...), Message Digest Algorithm (md5, ripemd160), HMAC-SHA, HMAC-MD, pbkdf2, Advanced Encryption Standard (AES), Triple Data Encryption Standard, (TripleDES, DES), RC4, Rabbit, ...">
  <meta property="og:type" content="website">
  <meta property="og:image" content="%PUBLIC_URL%/img/main.jpeg">
  <meta property="og:site_name" content="Cryptography">
  <meta property="og:locale" content="vi_VN">

  <!-- Twitter Card -->
  <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary">
  <meta name="twitter:site" content="@huynhsamha">
  <meta name="twitter:creator" content="@huynhsamha">
  <meta name="twitter:url" content="https://huynhsamha.github.io/crypto">
  <meta name="twitter:title" content="Cryptography Algorithms">
  <meta name="twitter:description" content="Cryptography Algorithms: Secure Hash Algorithm (sha256, sha512, ...), Message Digest Algorithm (md5, ripemd160), HMAC-SHA, HMAC-MD, pbkdf2, Advanced Encryption Standard (AES), Triple Data Encryption Standard, (TripleDES, DES), RC4, Rabbit, ...">
  <meta name="twitter:image:src" content="%PUBLIC_URL%/img/main.jpeg">

  <!--
      manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is added to the
      homescreen on Android. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/engage-and-retain/web-app-manifest/
    -->
  <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico">
  <link rel="author" href="//github.com/huynhsamha">
  <link rel="canonical" href="//huynhsamha.github.io/crypto">
  <!--
      Notice the use of %PUBLIC_URL% in the tags above.
      It will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build.
      Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced from the HTML.
      Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" will
      work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.
      Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`.
    -->
  <link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,700&amp;subset=vietnamese" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/lib/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">

  <!-- ------Single Page Apps GitHub Pages Workaround------ -->
  <script type="text/javascript">
    // Single Page Apps for GitHub Pages
    // https://github.com/rafrex/spa-github-pages
    // Copyright (c) 2016 Rafael Pedicini, licensed under the MIT License
    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    // This script checks to see if a redirect is present in the query string
    // and converts it back into the correct url and adds it to the
    // browser's history using window.history.replaceState(...),
    // which won't cause the browser to attempt to load the new url.
    // When the single page app is loaded further down in this file,
    // the correct url will be waiting in the browser's history for
    // the single page app to route accordingly.
    (function(l) {
      if (l.search) {
        var q = {};
        l.search.slice(1).split('&').forEach(function(v) {
          var a = v.split('=');
          q[a[0]] = a.slice(1).join('=').replace(/~and~/g, '&');
        });
        if (q.p !== undefined) {
          window.history.replaceState(null, null,
            l.pathname.slice(0, -1) + (q.p || '') +
            (q.q ? ('?' + q.q) : '') +
            l.hash
          );
        }
      }
    }(window.location))
   </script>


  <title>Cryptography</title>

</head>

<body>
  <noscript>
    You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
  </noscript>

  <div id="root"></div>

  <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.
      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.
      To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
      To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
    -->

  <script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/js/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/js/popper.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <!-- Google Adsense -->
  <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

More info and discussions on GitHub's support for single page app [here](https://github.com/isaacs/github/issues/408).

Comment: chrsep -- sorry, I totally duped your answer. I didn't notice it initially. For future reference, Stack Overflow answers do best when they synthesize the direct answer to the users problem and provide the solution instead of just providing links to resources. This *is* correct, however.

Comment: Hi @Jonny, it's okay, it's not a total dupe, the workaround i linked does the redirect in a different way. Thanks for the advice though, I'll update my answer to be more direct and specific.

Comment: I tried your solution and it still didn't work, but I also thank you for giving a solution

Answer (score 3):

Because, react app is onepage web, You need a **sitemap** file, you can find it how to make a one [here](https://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html) ,too make a 404 page, and every route add property that has a anchor
like to

```
<a title="This my Route One" href="https://myreactapp/routeOne" alt="Route One"/>
```

Comment: I tried your solution with creating simple `sitemap.xml` file and it still didn't work. Googlebot can find `/sitemap.xml` and discover all url I lists in this file, but it cannot `fetch and render` urls mentioned. Tnx

Comment: you can add it to robots.txt

Comment: File robots.txt I allow it with `User-agent: *`, Is it wrong?

Comment: User-agent: Googlebot, as preference , but i unknow if you need add meta tags refresh , like to "no cache"

Comment: Can you give me some preference about your idea?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're using a `404` page to capture incoming traffic to routes other than `/`. This means those routes serve a `404` status code (you can see this if you open Network in dev tools and try to visit one of those deep URLs). Google sees a `404` status in the response header and just gives up right away. You probably noticed that the "Not Found" message in Webmaster Tools popped up super-fast.

On a normal server, you would capture those routes and return a successful status code like `200` or `301` and Google would continue crawling. However, because you're using GitHub pages, you need to hack your way around it.

You should be able to do this by setting up an instant redirect from that `404` template to your index template. Browsers interpret instant redirects as `301`s. To do this, replace the contents of your `404.html` with something like this:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script>
    sessionStorage.redirect = location.href; // we'll use this later
  </script>
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL='/crypto'">
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

Just make sure the file-size of that `404.html` is greater than `512b` or IE will discard it (damn M$...).

Lastly, you'll need to make sure your `index.html` captures the original route. To do so, use a script like this in the head of your `index.html`:

```
<script>
  (function(){
    var redirect = sessionStorage.redirect; // remember me?
    delete sessionStorage.redirect;
    if (redirect && redirect != location.href) {
      history.replaceState(null, null, redirect);
    }
  })();
</script>
```

For reference, I stole this clever hack from:

https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/08/sghpa-single-page-app-hack-github-pages/

Comment: I tried your solution and it still didn't work, but I also thank you for giving a solution

Answer (score 0):

I also, do not see anything alarming in your code (although I don't *think* you need the `baseUrl` in your `<Route />` - though I could be wrong, and don't think that's the issue, but it may be worth eliminating if unnecessary).

Just a guess but looking at the networks tab as I bounced around the links, I noticed the service worker. I am, admittedly, not super savvy when it comes to service workers (yet!), however googling a bit revealed that google crawlers do not yet support service workers as asserted [in this article](https://www.advancedwebranking.com/blog/progressive-web-apps-that-dont-destroy-seo/), [this article](https://www.aymen-loukil.com/en/blog-en/things-you-need-to-know-about-google-wrs/),  and by [google](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/rendering).... I also noticed that if I run a Lighthouse test on one of the links I reached via in-app navigation (for instance I click on the `/algorithm` tab from the nav on the homepage and then run a Lighthouse test) I get the following errors:

> There were issues affecting this run of Lighthouse: Chrome extensions
>   negatively affected this page's load performance. Try auditing the
>   page in incognito mode or from a Chrome profile without extensions.

and *more interesting*:

> Lighthouse was unable to reliably load the page you requested. Make
>   sure you are testing the correct URL and that the server is properly
>   responding to all requests. Status code: 404.

...despite clearly seeing it rendered in the browser. Seems suspect. So, *if* that is part of how *navigation* is happening (seems it likely is based on the `registerServiceWorker.js` file in your repo lol), it may be the cause of your links not being found/followed.